# How to find $f'(c)$ and $f'(x)$ of the given problem.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Directions: Find $f '(x)$ and $f '(c)$

Function: $f(x) = \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}$

Value of $\;C: c = \dfrac{\pi}{6}$

I found $f '(x)$ which is $\dfrac{(x\cos(x)-\sin(x))}{x^2}$, but what is $f '(c)$? I just assume you'd plug in $\dfrac{\pi}{6}$ for $x$ in the derivative, but it's not the right answer on my digital homework.

Thanks!

Comment: This is correct. Did you replace the trigonometric functions by their values for $x=\frac \pi 6$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct so either the answer given on your digital homework is wrong, or you made a mistake in calculating or simplifying $f'(c)$; you should find:
$$\left.\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}\right|_{x=\tfrac{\pi}{6}}=\frac{\tfrac{\pi}{6}\cos\tfrac{\pi}{6}-\sin\tfrac{\pi}{6}}{\tfrac{\pi^2}{36}}=\frac{36\left(\tfrac{\pi}{6}\tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)}{\pi^2}=\frac{3\left(\sqrt{3}\pi-6\right)}{\pi^2}$$